# Animal skin storage

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

If I want to keep the animal skins for later use, do I have to put it on my horse or do I have to give them to Pearson ?

With legendary animal you can just sell the skin and still use it later, I assume it's not the case with regular animal skin ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to sell/donate skins to the correct vendor to use them for crafting. For the crafting in the camp, donate them to Pearson. The description will change from "donate for funds" to "donate for crafting" if it's something used for one of the crafting recipes.

There are also some crafting recipes from the Trapper that require non-legendary skins. As far as I understand you have to sell those to the Trapper to be able to craft them.

Comment: Can confirm any perfect pelts you sell to the trapper will be kept for crafting if they're needed.

Comment: Do the Trapper and Pearson not share an inventory of items you've sold them?

Comment: @DavidYell From what I read, they don't share an inventory. But I haven't verified that myself yet